# Como transformar texto em input text ao clicar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Então, to precisando transformar uma texto que está dentro de uma tag HTML em input text para editar ela. Qual melhor forma para fazer isso ?

Exemplo: http://www.codigopronto.com/codigos/Texto-editavel-com-JavaScript.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Que tal usar uma `div` (ou `p`, `span`, você que sabe) de conteúdo editável? [Existe um atributo só para isso](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp). Veja

```html
<p contenteditable="true">Este texto é editável. Clique aqui e veja funcionando.</p>
```

Acho que não fica mais fácil do que isso.

Comment: Caio o meu aqui deu certo cara, mas o primeiro caractere não edita. Você sabe o por quê disso?

Comment: Ja descobri cara, o elemento tem que ser bloco!

Answer (score 2):

a melhor forma de fazer isso é com javascript substituindo o campo de exibindo em um input, em seu exemplo já tem o javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
  function editTitle(){
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
    var span = title.firstChild;
    span.onmouseover = function(){
      this.title = 'Clique para editar o texto';
      this.style.background = '#f5f5f5';
    }
    span.onmouseout = function(){
      this.title = '';
      this.style.background = '';
    }
    span.onclick = function(){
      var textoAtual = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
      var input = '<input type="text" name="1" value="'+textoAtual+'">';
      this.innerHTML = input;
      var field = this.firstChild;
      this.onclick = null;
      this.onmouseover = null;
      field.focus();
      field.select();
      field.onblur = function(){
        this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.value;
        editTitle();
      }
    }
  }
  editTitle();
}
```

onde em `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]` ele especifica o elemento que ele deseja receber o texto e substituir por um input.

```
var input = '<input type="text" name="1" value="'+textoAtual+'">';
```

nessa parte ele insere o input, pegando o `textoAtual` que ele pegou no inicio da função do h1.
Caso tenha dúvida de como o código funciona comenta aqui,
deixei esse exemplo também nesse [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy2jo3w0/)